# How is からだ used here?

Tags: grammar, syntax

How should I parse the part that comes after 許さない:

> その形容から打突こそ主体と思われるが、槍｛やり｝の基本戦術は払いにある (1)。長さに物を言わせた広範囲の薙｛な｝ぎ払いは、もとより身を引いて躱｛かわ｝す、などという防御を許さない**からだ** (2)。

Feels like it makes the sentence flow a bit better with sentence topic but what is it, exactly? から_だ?　から used to affirm what's stated in (1) + copula for emphasis?

Comment: What do you understand so far?

Comment: "From this, it would seem that the most essential part is the strike itself. However, the basis of the spear-fighting martial technique is the sweep. The breadth of the sweep takes advantage of the (spear's) length - essentially, it doesn't allow you to dodge by (doing a thing like) side-stepping // moving your body to the side" What does からだ do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

「～～からだ」＝「～～からである」＝「～～からです」

> "から used to affirm what's stated in (1) + copula for emphasis?"

Kind of but not quite.  It affirms a prior statement by explaining the reason and/or logic behind the content of the prior statement.

The copula is **not** there for emphasis.  It is just needed there for the grammar reason.  In informal speech, it can be dropped and you could end a sentence with 「から」.

Statement #2 explains why the sweeping is the core of the spear fighting instead of the attacks.